# C# / SQL Server : error when creating stored procedure from C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

The below code is executed in C# Winforms. What I'm trying to do is creating tables and stored procedures when the program starts. I'm using `IF NOT EXISTS` in my SQL commands. If not exists, create, else do nothing.

Creating the tables is ok, it works beautifully.

But when creating stored procedures, Visual Studio throws this error;

> Must declare the scalar variable @xxxx

Before getting this error I was using `USE` and `GO` commands and this approach also gave `CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE` errors. As I researched on web, I gradually learnt that `USE` and `GO` is a no-no in C#. That's why I use `Else` instead of `GO` after `IF NOT EXISTS`.

The code works in T-SQL, but I guess I need to convert it to C# somehow.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

After I changed the StringBuilder to the just string, it fixed the previous error. Now it gives the below one. Couldn't find anything amiss though.

```
" System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    HResult=0x80131904
    Message=Incorrect Syntax near the 'Trendyol'.
  Unclosed quotation mark after the character string "', ')))))AS varchar) FROM urnBilgi INNER JOIN urn ON urn.stkID = bVeriID WHERE bVeriID = @stkID and bBilgiID = @bBilgiID AND(urn.fiyatS BETWEEN @fiyat_baslangic and @fiyat_bitis) END END'"
```

```
    public void createSP()
    {
        StringBuilder sbSP = new StringBuilder();

        sbSP.AppendLine(" IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND object_id = object_id('etradeCore'))" +
                        " exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[etradeCore]("  +

                        " ELSE"+ //Used Instead of GO
                     

                        " ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[etradeCore](" +
                        " @pazaryeri VARCHAR(50)," +
                        " @magaza VARCHAR(50)," +
                        " @stkID int," +
                        " @komisyon decimal(9, 4)," +
                        " @fiyat_baslangic decimal(9, 4)," +
                        " @fiyat_bitis decimal(9, 4)," +
                        " @eklenecekfiyat decimal(9, 4)" +
                        ")" +
                        
                        " AS BEGIN" +

                        " SET NOCOUNT OFF" +
                        " SET ANSI_NULLS ON" +
                        " SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON" +

                        " DECLARE @bBilgiID tinyint" +

                        " IF(@pazaryeri = 'Trendyol' and @magaza = 'Kozmeti')" +
                        " SET @bBilgiID = 58" +
                        " ELSE IF(@pazaryeri = 'Trendyol' and @magaza = 'Golden Rose')" +
                        " SET @bBilgiID = 52" +
                        " ELSE IF(@pazaryeri = 'Trendyol' and @magaza = 'Ziaja')" +
                        " SET @bBilgiID = 60" +
                        " ELSE IF(@pazaryeri = 'Hepsiburada' and @magaza = 'Kozmeti')" +
                        " SET @bBilgiID = 43" +
                        " ELSE IF(@pazaryeri = 'Hepsiburada' and @magaza = 'Golden Rose')" +
                        " SET @bBilgiID = 44" +
                        " ELSE IF(@pazaryeri = 'Hepsiburada' and @magaza = 'Ziaja')" +
                        " SET @bBilgiID = 43" +

                        " IF NOT EXISTS(select * from urnBilgi WHERE bVeriID = @stkID and bBilgiID = @bBilgiID and bDeger >= convert(varchar, 0))" +
                        " BEGIN" +
                        " INSERT INTO urnBilgi(bVeriID, bBilgiID, bDeger) VALUES(@stkID, @bBilgiID, '0')" +
                        " END" +
                        " ELSE" +
                        " BEGIN" +
                        " UPDATE urnBilgi SET bDeger =" +
                        " CAST(CONVERT(decimal(9, 4), ((((Select fiyatS from urn where stkID = @stkID) + @eklenecekfiyat)) *" +
                        " CONVERT(decimal(9, 4), convert(varchar, '1.' + REPLACE(@komisyon, '.', ''))) ))AS varchar)" +
                        " FROM urnBilgi" +
                        " INNER JOIN" +
                        " urn ON urn.stkID = bVeriID" +
                        " WHERE bVeriID = @stkID and bBilgiID = @bBilgiID AND(urn.fiyatS BETWEEN @fiyat_baslangic and @fiyat_bitis)" +
                        " END" +
                        " END" 
                        );
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sbSP.ToString(), connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using BEGIN and END to separate your logical blocks?

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? The "create or alter" was added in sql server 2016 with service pack 1. This functionality has been available ever since. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3190548-update-introduces-create-or-alter-transact-sql-statement-in-sql-server-2016-fd0596f3-9098-329c-a7a5-2e18f29ad1d4

Comment: The reason "GO" will not work in c# is because it is not a t-sql statement. It is the default batch separator in SSMS.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's 2014 @Sean Lange

Comment: @Tarzan No, but I will try rigt now because I guess I found the answer of the previous error. I used classic string instead of string builder, and the error is gone. Now it gives the error at the logical parts. I guess it is because I didn't use begin and end as you just have said.

Comment: Your code will still fail because it won't compile when the procedure already exists. You will probably have to drop the procedure and then always create it. If you have certain users that can execute that procedure you will have to add that back in. I would strongly suggest you start looking at upgrading your sql server version. 2014 fell out of mainstream support in 2019 meaning no new updates or patches. Extended support will be completely gone in 2 years.

Comment: You don't need a stringbuilder for this. There was a time where it was common advice to use stringbuilder if you had a lot of concatenation, but it only ever applied if there were variables or loops involved. For this string, the compiler will optimize away an concatenation penalty. There will be no performance difference (or maybe even improvement) if you switch to a regular string variable.

Comment: You need the entire proc body in both the `CREATE` and `ALTER` statements, like `IF NOT EXISTS...EXEC(N'CREATE...) ELSE EXEC(N'ALTER'`. You might find it easier to conditionally drop the proc and then and unconditional create.

Comment: You don't need to check the existence of your stored proc if you're running from c#; if the proc exists the attempt to create it will fail, and c# will experience an exception that you can ignore. Keep it simple

Comment: Also, you really should use @ strings (verbatim strings) and you should indent your sproc code; that code's a mess I wouldn't want to maintain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `GO` in a SQL batch with `SqlCommand`. It is not valid T-SQL, it's just a batch separator used by sqlcmd and SSMS.

Instead you need to split batches by using a new command.

However in this particular instance, you don't actually need two commands. Firstly because you can combine them using `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`. Secondly even if you did need to, since you are just doing this via dynamic SQL you can just conditionally build a dynamic SQL script to pass through.

You can also remove the `StringBuilder` and use a verbatim `@""` string instead. This allows you to insert newlines and make good use of whitespace.

Another issue with your current script is that you are not escaping `'` for the dynamic SQL. Passing it in as a parameter as I have done avoids this, but if you want to do it all in one big batch you need to make sure to do so.

```cs
public void createSP()
{
    const string sqlExec = @"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.procedures
    WHERE name = 'etradeCore')
  exec(@sql);
";

    const string sbSP = @"
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[etradeCore]
  @pazaryeri VARCHAR(50),
  @magaza VARCHAR(50),
  @stkID int,
  @komisyon decimal(9, 4),
  @fiyat_baslangic decimal(9, 4),
  @fiyat_bitis decimal(9, 4),
  @eklenecekfiyat decimal(9, 4)
AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

DECLARE @bBilgiID tinyint =
  CASE @pazaryeri
  WHEN 'Trendyol'
    THEN
      CASE @magaza
      WHEN 'Kozmeti'
        THEN 58
      WHEN 'Golden Rose'
        THEN 52
      WHEN 'Ziaja'
        THEN 60
      END
  WHEN 'Hepsiburada'
    THEN
      CASE @magaza
      WHEN 'Kozmeti'
        THEN 43
      WHEN 'Golden Rose'
        THEN 44
      WHEN 'Ziaja'
        THEN 43
      END
  END;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM urnBilgi
    WHERE bVeriID = @stkID
      AND bBilgiID = @bBilgiID
      AND bDeger >= '0')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO urnBilgi (bVeriID, bBilgiID, bDeger)
    VALUES (@stkID, @bBilgiID, '0');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE b
    SET bDeger = CAST(
      CONVERT(decimal(9, 4),
        (
          u.fiyatS + @eklenecekfiyat
        ) * CONVERT(decimal(9, 4), '1.' + REPLACE(@komisyon, '.', ''))
      ) AS varchar(30))
    FROM urnBilgi b
    INNER JOIN urn u ON u.stkID = b.bVeriID
    WHERE b.bVeriID = @stkID
      AND b.bBilgiID = @bBilgiID
      AND (u.fiyatS BETWEEN @fiyat_baslangic AND @fiyat_bitis);
END
"; 

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlExec, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@sql", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = sbSP;
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` should be part of the connection string settings, not part of the batch
- Use `sys.procedures` instead of `sys.objects`
- Use `EXISTS (SELECT 1` instead of `EXISTS (SELECT *`
- It's unclear why you are passing `@komisyon` as a decimal only to remove the `.` perhaps you should pass an `int` instead, or perhaps some other way.
- Always declare `varchar` with a length.
- Why is `bDeger` a `varchar` anyway? Should it not be `decimal`?
- Unclear why you need the inner `SELECT fiyatS...` subquery in the `UPDATE` and not just `u.fiyatS`.
- `CommandType.Text` is the default.
- There is no need to call `Close()` if you have a `using` block (as you should).
- Why is `SET NOCOUNT OFF`? Normally it's better to leave it on.
- This whole "upsert" procedure [should probably be in a transaction, with `HOLDLOCK` hints](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern), and should probably use `@@ROWCOUNT` to check.

Comment: It was a good lesson, thank you. As for the variables and their types, let just them be. I first tried as you said but the table I'm trying to update is confusing, so it gave me lots of problems. Thank you for the advices. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72019263/c-sharp-sql-server-error-when-creating-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-code/72019871#comment127256786_72019263) is alright for now. Even though the real problem is not solved, I skipped the next step in my program.

> You don't need to check the existence of your stored proc if you're running from c#; if the proc exists the attempt to create it will fail, and c# will experience an exception that you can ignore. Keep it simple